# X the real line with the topology in which the open sets are the sets of form $(a,\infty)$

Tags: general-topology

X the real line with the topology in which the open sets are the sets of form $(a,\infty), a \in \mathbb{R}$. Answer:

1. Which sequences converge to which points?
2. Is X first countable?
3. if $E \subset X$, then $x \in cl(E)$ iff there is a sequence $(x_{n})$ contained in $E$ which converges to $x$.

We conclude the third question if X is first countable but I no have idea to prove it, it would be more difficult if $X$ isn't countable. So, could you guide me please?

Answer (score 0):

1) $x_n \to x$ iff $x \le \liminf_n x_n$. An interesting exercise in definitions.

2) Yes, a local base at $x$ is $\{(x-\frac{1}{n}, +\infty): n \in \Bbb N\}$ because for any $(a, +\infty)$ that contains $x$, so when $a < x$, we have some $n$ with $a < x-\frac{1}{n} < x$ by the Archimedian property of $\Bbb R$.

3) is true and follows from b) in all spaces.